# Confuse about exam question :/

Tags: american-english, british-english, questions

This came from a past [TOEIC](https://www.ets.org/toeic) Paper and you're supposed to pick the incorrect underlined part.

***While*** most of these technologies are still in ***its*** early stages of development and many will no doubt prove ***impractical*** , others are clearly on the edge of commercial application or ***will be*** within a decade or two.

The words that were underlined were : **while**, **its**, **impractical**, **will be**. The answer sheet says **its** is the answer however I don't really understand why. Anyone else understand this particular grammar point and can explain?

Comment: I figured it out ....

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! It's great that you were able to figure this out on your own—we really appreciate users who are trying hard to find their own answer. if you would like, you can actually answer your own question, in the answer box below; that might help someone else out in the future, but of course it isn't required.

Answer (score 0):

Well at first glance I thought 'its' was correct nothing seemed off it's how o a native speaker would speak. But then I noticed it could also be replaced with 'the'. Still in the early stages of development makes sense as well.

After speaking to many friend they also didn't pick up on this because using it's might just be the natural way we speak. Atleast I hope that's the explanation for this question, correct me if I'm wrong though.

Comment: Actually the issue is that *its* is referring to "most of these technologies". "Most of these technologies" is a plural noun phrase, and *its* is singular. You have correctly identified what is wrong, but perhaps not clearly why it is. Here, *its* would be most usefully replaced by *their*.

Comment: Yea I really didn't pick up on that at all but thank you so much for explaining!! I can now explain to everyone else who didn't notice lol